# Best way to send bulk emails BCC vs Individual?

Tags: email, sendmail, bulk

My development team has gotten into a fight with systems about how bulk emails should be sent out via a sendmail server.  Currently when development sends out a 1000 recipient email, we put them in the BCC and send 1 email to the server.  It is our expectation that the email server will do what it needs to to handle the "job".  We do this because we want the process to be atomic from our side.  So either we sent it to the mailserver or we didn't.  We do not want to send them individually, because if the process fails at any point then we have to figure out the work that didn't get done and pick up where we left off.

Systems insists that is is weird to send 1000 recipients on a BCC and this is causing sendmail to hit file descriptor limits.  Which are in place to stop DoS attacks, and to change will require compiling our own sendmail.

Development is calling BS because we are going to send the mailserver the same amount of work no matter what.

Can we get an outside opinion?

Comment: Are you going to send o a few fixed/stable lists of recipients? How many bounce email  messages do you expect?

Comment: Have you seen this SO post?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519787/php-e-mail-efficiency-bcc-vs-individual-e-mails